# Cannot assign to a reference or variable - ivy

Tags: angular

when i set extra var in `ngFor` -

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel
        *ngFor="let group of selectedPanel.settings; let panelOpenState = false"
        (closed)="panelOpenState = false"
        (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
    >
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

and with compiling with ivy i get real time error:

```
  Cannot assign to a reference or variable
```

it is a bug?

should i need to avoiding this?

there is another way to declare var in loop scope?

Comment: Let's suppose it should work. what you gonna do with your panelOpenState after closing or opening? :)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Why don't you set value in controller side?

Comment: @Pardeep Jain yes, i can set some dictionary in controller, but this is prettier..

Comment: @yantrab No, also It is not recommended to bind any value in the template side, everytime in change detection it will bind the value again and agian.